# Java Joptionpane not showing with else statement

Tags: java, joptionpane

I wrote this code for my updater class but for some reason It wont get to the `Joptionpane` after the `}else{` statement at the bottom:

`JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Currently no updates available!!");`

Instead it'll just `return` out.. which is good but I'd also like it to notify the user. I updated with formatting...
intcurrentversion = 2, so it should run the `Joptionpane`

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    ImageIcon updateicon = new ImageIcon("resources/update.png");
    String url = "http://example.com/wp-content/uploads/version/Version.html";
    Document document = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
    String getcurrentversion = document.select("version").first().text();  
    int intcurrentversion = Integer.parseInt(getcurrentversion);    
    System.out.println(intcurrentversion);

    if (intcurrentversion > 2) {

        int response = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Would you like to update?", "Update available!",
            JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION, JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE,updateicon);

        if (response == JOptionPane.NO_OPTION) {
            System.out.println("No button clicked");
        } else if (response == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION) {
            System.out.println("Yes button clicked");

            {
                String filePath = "C:/Windows/Updater.exe";//
                try {
                    Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(filePath);

                } catch (Exception g) {
                    g.printStackTrace();
                }
            }


        } else {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Currently no updates available!!");

        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: If you fix the indentation, so the indentation matches what the code actually does, then it will be obvious.

Comment: This is why code formatting matters so much. Don't ignore it.

Comment: yes, sorry hopefully that is better!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is your program with the indentation fixed:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;

public class CheckForUpdate {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        ImageIcon updateicon = new ImageIcon("resources/update.png");
        String url = "http://example.com/wp-content/uploads/version/Version.html";
        Document document = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
        String getcurrentversion = document.select("version").first().text();  
        int intcurrentversion = Integer.parseInt(getcurrentversion);    
        System.out.println(intcurrentversion);

        if (intcurrentversion > 0) {

            int response = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Would you like to update?", "Update available!",
                JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION, JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE,updateicon);

            if (response == JOptionPane.NO_OPTION) {
                System.out.println("No button clicked");
            } else if (response == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION) {
                System.out.println("Yes button clicked");

                {
                    String filePath = "C:/Windows/Updater.exe";//
                    try {
                        Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(filePath);

                    } catch (Exception g) {
                        g.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }


            } else {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Currently no updates available!!");

            }
        }
    }
}
```

I hope it is now obvious why the message doesn't get displayed when intcurrentversion <= 0.

Comment: Thanks for that, I have changed my question a bit. So `intcurrentversion = 2` and I have it as `if (intcurrentversion > 2) {` so it should run that 'JOptionPane'.

Comment: @javajoejuan: he already explained why the previous and the current versions aren't working as you've expected it. Use good indentation, then use your eyeballs to tell you what level the else should be on. 1+ to this answer.